# how can I get, which "SerialPort" has triggered the given "DataReceived" event?

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

I need to read from several serial ports at the same time.

I know I should use multithreading but yet I don't know how I should.

I can handle the event with "SerialDataReceivedEventArgs" assigning the ".DataReceived" event to the SerialPort object.

But when it's triggered I can't see which port triggered the event. So I don't know which ports should I read.

I tried to take it into a new thread assigning specific different names to the threads, but when I use this:

```
private void CheckSerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        //this code runs on another thread. It is not running on the thread where the SerialPort was opened.

    }
```

The same thing has happened if I triy this:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayThreadText));
    }
private void DisplayThreadText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this code runs on the main thread. It is not running on the thread where the SerialPort was opened.
    }
```

So my question is that how can I get, which port has triggered the given event?

Or should I use other methods? I don't know...

But if you can help me out I would appreciate that.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialdatareceivedeventhandler): _"**sender** [Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object)
The sender of the event, which is the SerialPort object."_. I don't understand your question. The documentation clearly explains that the `sender` parameter passed to your handler tells you exactly which `SerialPort` object is raising the event. What more do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sender object is the SerialPort.

```
public static void Main()
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");

        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;

        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        mySerialPort.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
        mySerialPort.Close();
    }

    private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                        object sender,
                        SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
        Console.Write(indata);
    }
```